# Can APK files be decompiled and rebuild to App Bundle?

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

Is it possible to decompile an APK file and rebuild it to an .abb file (App Bundle) For publish in Google play console?

Comment: why can not you create the .aab file directly from the android studio?

Answer (score 0):

An APK usually is a subset of an App Bundle. Under normal circumstances you can not re-create the original App Bundle from an existing APK.

If you have the universal APK this would be possible, but there is no supported tooling for this. Building a new App Bundle from source is the recommended way to go.